# error #29 Expected an expression in C

Tags: bluetooth

Code snippet :

```
#define ATT_UUID_SIZE                    16

#define ATT_BT_UUID_SIZE                 2

typedef unsigned char   uint8;

typedef struct
{
  uint8 len;                 //!< Length of UUID (2 or 16)
  uint8 uuid[ATT_UUID_SIZE]; //!< 16 or 128 bit UUID
} attAttrType_t; 

typedef struct
{
  uint16 startHandle; 
  uint16 endHandle;   
  attAttrType_t type; 
} attReadByTypeReq_t;

attReadByTypeReq_t req;
req.startHandle=svcStartHdl;
req.endHandle=svcEndHdl;
req.type.len=ATT_BT_UUID_SIZE;
req.type.uuid[ATT_BT_UUID_SIZE]={0xAD,0x2B};
```

=> it says error #29 when I assign 0xAD and 0x2B to as the uuid what could i be doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
req.type.uuid[ATT_BT_UUID_SIZE]={0xAD,0x2B};
```

This line is not correct. uuid of uuid[xxx] is an array address, which can't be assigned a value via '=' method. Do like this:

```
req.type.uuid[0] = 0xAD; 
req.type.uuid[1] = 0x2B;
```

or like this:

```
memcpy(req.type.uuid, YOUR_VALUE, ATT_BT_UUID_SIZE);
```

Comment: It is good practice to describe the code you post. Also, olease use words instead of symbols like "==>" which the OP or other community members  may not understand.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.